# Inline latex code not showing in R Markdown Notebook when using latex_options from kableExtra package

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, kableextra

When I specify `latex_options` from the `kableExtra` package in my R Markdown notebook, my inline latex code does not show after I run all code chunks. I've tried viewing it in Rstudio Preview or viewing the html in Google Chrome, but neither works (I'm not talking about viewing it in Rstudio's editor). When I remove the `latex_options` line, my inline latex code shows correctly. When I render using `rmarkdown::render()` (instead of running all code chunks in Rstudio), my inline latex code shows correctly. How can I get my inline latex code to show when using specifying `latex_options` from the `kableExtra` package?

Here's a reproducible example where the inline latex code does *not* show correctly—**make sure to run all code chunks before previewing**:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library("kableExtra")
```

Table with latex options from kableExtra package:

```{r}
kable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down"))
```

This works:

$$
x=\frac{1}{2}
$$

This does not work:

$x=\frac{1}{2}$
````

Here's a reproducible example where the inline latex code shows correctly:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library("kableExtra")
```

Table with latex options from kableExtra package:

```{r}
kable(head(mtcars))
```

This works:

$$
x=\frac{1}{2}
$$

This also works:

$x=\frac{1}{2}$
````

Here's my sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] kableExtra_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.30        xml2_1.3.2        magrittr_2.0.1    rvest_0.3.6       munsell_0.5.0     colorspace_2.0-0 
 [8] viridisLite_0.3.0 R6_2.5.0          rlang_0.4.9       stringr_1.4.0     httr_1.4.2        highr_0.8         tools_4.0.2      
[15] webshot_0.5.2     packrat_0.5.0     xfun_0.19         htmltools_0.5.0   fortunes_1.5-4    yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.27    
[22] lifecycle_0.2.0   glue_1.4.2        evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_2.6     stringi_1.5.3     compiler_4.0.2    scales_1.1.1     
[29] jsonlite_1.7.2
```

Here's my Rstudio version:

```
> rstudioapi::versionInfo()

$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.3.1056’

$release_name
[1] "Water Lily"
```

Comment: They both show up for me when I preview the notebook.  Only the first shows up in RStudio's editor, whether or not I call `kable_extra`.  I'm on a Mac, not Windows.

Comment: Did you run all code chunks before previewing? The preview looks good until I ran all code chunks (including the line with "latex_options"). I updated the description of the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue if I follow the edited instructions carefully.

To try to debug it, I wrote a tiny R package containing a function `wrap_notebook <- function(...) html_notebook(...)`, and set that as the output format.  This fixed (or at least masked) the issue.

So I don't know what went wrong, but at least there's a workaround.

The original issue probably warrants a bug report to RStudio.

Comment: This was very helpful--it shows fine when using `rmarkdown::render()` (instead of running all code chunks in Rstudio). Thanks for helping me find a workaround. And I just submitted a bug report to Rstudio--much appreciated!